# I want to make AnimationCurve to orthogonal in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to make an `AnimationCurve` like this picture in script and apply.

[image]

but if i make and apply `AnimationCurve`, it's fail like this picture.

```
{
    AnimationCurve curve = new AnimationCurve();

    curve.AddKey(0.0f, 0.1f);
    curve.AddKey((float)(colCount*2 + rowCount*2+3) / gridPoint.Count, 0.1f);
    curve.AddKey((float)(colCount*2 + rowCount*2+3) / gridPoint.Count, 0.02f);
    curve.AddKey(1, 0.02f);
    lr.widthCurve = curve;
}
```

I want AnimationCurve in script like first picture
how do i make this curve in script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `AddKey(float time, float value)` you could use `AddKey(Keyframe key)`. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.AddKey.html).

The [`Keyframe`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Keyframe.html) struct allows you to specify more stuff, like the weights, tangents and weighted mode.